# swift 2 - file not found error when reading text file from app main bundle

Tags: ios, swift, nsbundle

I added a simple text file (savedinfo.txt) to my project containing just 1 line of text. I need to read the text from within my app. I did that as below. However, for some reasons, it cannot find the file when reading it, even though sFilePath shows the file path. See debug msg below. I am using the latest Xcode 7.2.

Thanks

```
let sFilePath = String(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("savedinfo", ofType: "txt")

let sText =  try NSString(contentsOfFile: sFilePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

> sFilePath: Optional("/Users/user115387/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F3866C2A-869A-4CE5-9936-C8BC0CC5CE0D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A98B6D45-1C9A-4049-86F1-9502D45836B0/TableViewDemo.app/savedinfo.txt")
>
> error in reading file Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “savedinfo.txt")” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Comment: Is the file listed in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources of the target? And why do you create a `String` from an expression which returns a `String` anyway?

Comment: Yes, savedinfo.txt is listed in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. I deleted and added it back there but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
        if let sFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("savedinfo", ofType: "txt") {
        do {
            let sText = try NSString(contentsOfFile: sFilePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(sText)
        }catch {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I figured out the issue. I was using  both NSBundle.mainbundle and NSString methods in a custom class that I created. I moved over the NSBundle.mainbundle to ViewController and it works fine!!!